# JavaScript Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method

Tags: javascript

I am trying to make a basic JavaScript 'library' / tool which helps the user change items using their IDs. I have tried a basic function, but I get the error `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object global] has no method 'val'`, and I am not sure why:

lib.js

```
function $id(id)
{
    if(id)
    {
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No ID found when using $id(...)");
    }
}
$id.prototype = 
{
    val: function()
    {
        return this.elem.value;
    },
    set: function(v)
    {
        this.elem.value = v;
    },
    destroy: function()
    {
        this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(this.elem);
    }

}
```

index.html

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="lib.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
alert($id("myDiv").val());
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">
Hello
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please try alert(new $id("myDiv").val());

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have a few small issues within your code above.

First, to directly answer your question: you need to use "new" when attempting to output the result, as follows:

```
alert(new $id("myDiv").val());
```

Second, you will need to place the script tag that outputs the value *below* the element being referenced. With your current example, the "myDiv" element does not yet exist in the DOM when the script is run.

Finally, to get the contents of a DIV, getting the value will return null. Rather, you need to get the innerHTML of the element.

Here's an updated version of your code to achieve the result that I believe you are hoping for:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script>
function $id(id)
{
    if(id)
    {
        this.elem = document.getElementById(id);
        return this;
    }
    else
    {
        console.log("No ID found when using $id(...)");
    }
}
$id.prototype = 
{
    html: function()
    {
        return this.elem.innerHTML;
    },
    set: function(v)
    {
        this.elem.value = v;
    },
    destroy: function()
    {
        this.elem.parentNode.removeChild(this.elem);
    }

}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<div id="myDiv">Hello</div>
<script>alert(new $id("myDiv").html());</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

Invoking `$id(...)` instead of `new $id(...)` means that the function doesn't act like a construction and you don't have access to the prototype.

Try this

```
alert(new $id("myDiv").val());
```

See [Inheritance and the prototype chain](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) on MDN.

As mentioned in the comments, `.value` is undefined on your `div` and event if it "works", your alert box will show `undefined`. You might be looking for `.innerHTML`.

Here's a [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/r4zNN/1/).

Comment: @SumanBogati It works here: http://jsfiddle.net/r4zNN/1/ It alerts `undefined` but that's because `value` is undefined on that element. OP would have to change that to `innerHTML` or whatever else he wants to access with `.val`...

Comment: Oh..undefined did confuse me.